# Is there a way to check if script is running from subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

Let's say I have a python script which reads all the images in a folder and resizes them. The script works all by his own, it takes in two arguments - the input folder and an output folder.
To have a visual response of the progress I'm using a progressbar which is printed out to the console/terminal.

**resize.py:**

```
import argparse
import fnmatch
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from progress.bar import Bar

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Photo resizer.')
parser.add_argument('input_folder', nargs='?', default='', help="Input folder")
parser.add_argument('export_folder', nargs='?', default='', help="Output folder")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.input_folder:
    input_folder = args.input_folder
if args.export_folder:
    export_resized_folder = args.export_folder

NEW_SIZE = 2000

inputFiles = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(input_folder):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.jpg'):
        inputFiles.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

bar = Bar("Processing photos", max=len(inputFiles), check_tty=False)
for photo in inputFiles:
    filename = os.path.basename(photo)
    im = Image.open(photo)
    im_width, im_height = im.size
    if im_width > im_height:
        new_width = NEW_SIZE
        new_height = int(NEW_SIZE * im_height / im_width)
    else:
        new_height = NEW_SIZE
        new_width = int(NEW_SIZE * im_width / im_height)
    new_size = (new_width, new_height)
    im_resized = im.resize(new_size, resample=PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    im_resized.save(os.path.join(export_resized_folder, filename), quality=70)
    bar.next()
bar.finish()
```

Now I have an another script (main_gui.py) which does some batch processing and one of the jobs is to resize the images. This script provides a simple GUI. When it comes to resizing the images, I use `subprocess Popen` to execute the script and pass in the input and output folders as args.

So in **main_gui.py** I start the subprocess:

```
script_path = "resize.py"
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", script_path, INPUT_FOLDER, OUTPUT_FOLDER], universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now I'd like to see the progress in the GUI also. I don't know if I'm doing it correctly (It is a high probability that not, this is just the first thing that came to my mind)...
So in **resize.py** along with the progressbar I print out information about my progress and then read it in the **main_gui.py** and based on that information I update a tkinter progressbar.

In **resize.py**:

```
bar = Bar("Processing photos", max=len(inputFiles), check_tty=False)
print("**TOTAL** " + str(len(inputFiles)))
...
progressCounter = 1
for photo in inputFiles:
   ...
   bar.next()
   print("**PROGRESS** " + str(progressCounter)) 
   progressCounter += 1
   ...
```

I read these values in **main_gui.py**

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", script_path], universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while process.poll() is None:
    data = process.stdout.readline().strip()
    print(data)
    if "**TOTAL** " in data:
        total = int(data.replace("**TOTAL** ", ""))
        progressbarWidget['maximum'] = total
    if "**PROGRESS** " in data and self.GUI:
        progressCounter = int(data.replace("**PROGRESS** ", ""))
        progressbarWidget['value'] = progressCounter
        progressbarWidget.update_idletasks()
```

And at this point I'd like in my **resize.py** check if it is run by itself or by the subprocess, so I don't have the unnecessary print statements.

I tried pass in an env value as Charles suggested in the comments, but couldn't get it done

Comment: You're always a subprocess of _something_. If you want to look up what it is, that's what `PPID` is for.

Comment: That said, what's the real-world use case for making the distinction? For a lot of purposes it's more appropriate to check whether stdout is connected to a TTY, for example.

Comment: Another approach (there are plenty of options!) is to use an environment variable to signal to your subprocess that it should behave in the manner appropriate to a given usage mode.

Comment: Can you please post some code of one of these options?

Comment: I'd need to understand _why_ you're doing this to know which option is best. That's why I asked.

Comment: Also, to be more explicit about the approaches I already told you about... `ls -l /proc/$PPID/exe`; or, on the `subprocess` side, see the `env=` option to `Popen`; if you pass something like `{'started_by_script1': '1'}` to the existing environment, there you are. And the third, checking whether stdout is a tty -- `if [ -t 1 ]; then echo "This output is going to a terminal"; else echo "This output is going to a pipeline, like maybe a Python process"; fi`

Comment: ...in general, if all you're doing is deciding whether to write some content to stdout, have you considered being explicit? `subprocess.Popen(['python', script_path, '--dump-to-stdout'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: (obvs, in a Python script you'll want to change `ls -l /proc/$PPID/exe` to an `os.readlink()` operation)

Comment: (and also obvs, in a Python script you'll want to use `os.getppid()` instead of `$PPID`)

Comment: I updated my question, so you get a better understanding.

Comment: That helps a lot. BTW, it's conventional for status bars meant for human consumption to go to stderr, not stdout (information on a process's progress is considered "diagnostic", and the POSIX standard says that stdout is only for "regular" output whereas stderr is for "diagnostic" output; shell prompts go there too, for that matter, because information about when the system is ready for more input is also diagnostic in nature and meant for a human reader rather than the software on the other end of a pipeline).

Comment: (on a more practical note, stdout is either fully buffered or line-buffered by default depending on whether it's going to a TTY; so if you want your progress data written to stdout to be available to read immediately, you may need to flush it explicitly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to detect your parent process is an unnecessary amount of magic for this use case. Making it explicit with an optional argument will let others writing their own GUIs (potentially in non-Python languages) get the machine-readable status output without needing to try to fool the detection.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Photo resizer.')
parser.add_argument('--progress', choices=('none', 'human', 'machine-readable'), default='none',
                    help="Should a progress bar be written to stderr in a human-readable form, to stdout in a machine-readable form, or not at all?")
parser.add_argument('input_folder', nargs='?', default='', help="Input folder")
parser.add_argument('export_folder', nargs='?', default='', help="Output folder")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

...and then later...

```
if args.progress == 'machine-readable':
  pass # TODO: Write your progress messages for the programmatic consumer to stdout here
elif args.progress == 'human':
  pass # TODO: Write your progress bar for a human reader to stderr here
```

while on the GUI side, adding `--progress=human` to the argument list:

```
process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, script_path, '--progress=human'],
                           universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: This is way more simple and nicer than what I tried to do. Haven't thought this way. Thank you!